# Enabling zombies stops my app from crashing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

My app crashes right here at this line:

```
- (void)setXOffset:(CGFloat)xOffset {
    _xOffset = xOffset;

    _backingTextField.frame = (CGRect) {
        .origin.x = - round(xOffset * 2.f) / 2.f,
        .origin.y = NSMinY(_backingTextField.frame), // <-- This is it
        .size = _backingTextField.frame.size,
    };

    [self _reloadMask];
}
```

I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` meaning the instance `_backingTextField` has been deallocated. I tried enabling zombie objects but when I do my app does not crash anymore. I get no logs, nothing. I couldn't reproduce using Instruments either.

Another thing is that the object seems still to be in memory

[image]

But that might just be because the pointer points to that location in memory and the memory hasn't been overwritten yet.

Any idea what might be causing the problem?

## EDIT

What's also weird is that `_backingTextField` is a strong reference. This shouldn't ever be released before the object itself gets released.

## EDIT 2

What's worth nothing is that this method is called automatically by the `animator` proxy.

```
self.animator.xOffset = xOffset;
```

## EDIT 3

I just tried making `_backingTextField` a weak reference, not even that helps.

Comment: Try replacing `_backingTextField` with an instance of a subclass with a custom dealloc method that e.g. logs when called?

Comment: @tsnorri I found out what the issue was, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I have accidentally overridden the `dealloc` method in a `NSView` category. This caused the subviews of the `NSView` not to be released properly and introduced other odd side effects.

Impossible to debug...